# dir-paginate controls not showing

Tags: dirpagination

I've got this:

```
        <div class="row services">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6" dir-paginate="item in listings | itemsPerPage: 4">
                  <center>
                    <a href="{{ item.steamname }}"><h4>{{ item.profilename }}</h4></a>
                    <img src="{{item.rank }}" />
          <p>{{ item.location }}</p>
        </center>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
                    <center><dir-pagination-controls></dir-pagination-controls></center>
```

For some reason the controls are not showing at all..

Not even sure where to start. The actual pagination is cutting down the listings to `4` as requested but the rest doesn't show...

Comment: Did you find the cause or the solution to it? I have been using this for so many projects but suddenly for my current project I'm facing a similar issue as you are.

Answer (score 2):

You should put `total-items="10"` after the `dir-paginate="item in listings | itemsPerPage: 4"`

the whole code looks like this,

```
<div class="row services">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6" dir-paginate="item in listings | itemsPerPage: 4" total-items="10">
        <center>
            <a href="{{ item.steamname }}"><h4>{{ item.profilename }}</h4></a>
            <img src="{{item.rank }}" />
            <p>{{ item.location }}</p>
        </center>
    </div>
</div>

<center><dir-pagination-controls></dir-pagination-controls></center>
```

And also make sure `total-items` should be greater than `itemsPerPage`

Comment: `And also make sure total-items should be greater than itemsPerPage` saved time

Answer (score 1):

1. Firstly download the [dirPagination.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/master/src/directives/pagination/dirPagination.js) from here.
2. Include the dirPagination.js file on your page like :

> `<script src="~/Content/dirPagination.js"></script>`

3. After that add dir-paginate directive for pagination in script
   file.code given below :

> angular.module('myApp', ['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);

4. Then in div tag add given line of code :

> ```
>  <div  dir-paginate="item in listings|itemsPerPage:4">
> ```

5. Then add pagination control in your HTML page for putting buttons of First,Next,Previous and Last.Code given below :

   `<dir-pagination-controls
            max-size="10"
           direction-links="true"
           boundary-links="true" >
   </dir-pagination-controls>`